# Azure Android SDK - Active Directory Authentication - How to get Roles?

Tags: android, azure, mbaas

How could I get hold of role (custom) details from the Active Directory once successfully authenticated. I am developing an android application using Azure as MBaaS and followed the link for enabling authentication

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users/

but I am not sure on how to get the roles and user details once user successfully logged in. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known, you can try to get the custom role details from Azure AD using Azure AD Graph API, please refer to the offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-graph-api) to know it.

Meanwhile, you can search [`graphapi`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graphapi&type=&language=) on GitHub of Azure Samples to get the code samples as references for your Azure MBaaS Application.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi Peter,Yes, I got it done by using graph API and of course it was not straightforward. Thanks.